# How to detect what underlying VGA Video Mixing Render 7 is using?

Tags: directshow

We have a issue that specific combinations of filters including VMR7 causes frame is not rendered right. We noticed it is only happened with certain GPU card with some of driver versions.

We try to make some workaround (with some overhead) only for the GPU. Is any way to know the underlying VGA card associated with the VMR7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answers for my question.

There is monitor related information interface `IVMRMonitorConfig` which is query-able from `VMR7 filter` to ask about device information which is associated.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390488(v=vs.85).aspx

```
IVMRMonitorConfig::GetAvailableMonitors(
    [out] VMRMONITORINFO *pInfo,
    [in]  DWORD          dwMaxInfoArraySize,
    [out] DWORD          *pdwNumDevices
);
```

I can recognize the specific VGA card by the keyword in `VMRMONITORINFO::szDevice` or `VMRMONITORINFO::szDescription` string.